GuzzleHTTP requestAsync Custom Timeout Not Working
I create a client object with GuzzleHTTP and use the requestAsync method. I don't have any problems so far. However, I set the options timeout value to 60 in RequestAsync and experiment. However, the waiting time never exceeds 30 seconds. I examined php.ini nginx and all laravel configuration files and couldn't find anything that would cause this.
This project is a Php - Laravel
Client Generate
$client = new Client(['http_errors' => false, 'verify' => false]);

Example Request
$options = [
  'auth' => "token",
  'connect_timeout' => 5,
  'timeout' => 60,
];

$handlerStack = HandlerStack::create();
$handlerStack->push(Middleware::tap(before: function (RequestInterface $r) use (&$sentRequest) {
   return $sentRequest = $r;
}));

$promise = $this->client->requestAsync(
   $request->method(),
   $route,
   $options + [
     'handler' => $handlerStack,
     'on_stats' => function (TransferStats $s) use (&$transferTime) {
        $transferTime = $s->getTransferTime();
     },
  ]
);

$promise->wait();

I researched the problem a lot, but I couldn't find an option other than the methods I currently use. My goal is to allow timeout up to 90 seconds.
An example error output: URL error 28: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
I checked all conf files on php, nginx and laravel, I checked my code blocks repeatedly and as far as I researched, everything is correct here. My expectation is to support timeout value up to 90 seconds. However, no matter what I did, I could not achieve this result. It always gives a timeout of 30 seconds.

Hi, I found my problem. All the flows I mentioned above were correct. I was using Octane via Laravel app and I noticed that there was a max_execution_time value in it. Basically I was having problems due to Octane.
Changing the max_execution_time value in the Octane config solved the problem for me.

Had a similar issue.
In my case, the request was cached by the web server.
Try adding a cache control header (with no-store) for testing purposes.

The question about the timeout setting, not the caching behaviour.

That's correct. Nevertheless, I have found that setting a timeout does not have an immediate effect if the request/response remains cached by the web server, for example.
Therefore, in my opinion, my answer to the question is correct.
